# Array Interpolation Optimization

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, 2d

My problem is mainly about python optimization. I want to create a Geotiff file from an unstructured point cloud. Until now, I could create my tiff file from a 2D array of my points.

Only, it is an array of size (10000, 9300), which contains too many NaN values that I would like to interpolate.
[image: --> Tiff file without intrerpolation]

The values to interpolate are in white on the capture.
Another constraint, I must not interpolate the values outside the project area, by extrapolation. Outside the convex area.

I have already managed to produce a result using griddata from scipy but the processing time is not viable (~15min) as I have to repeat this on a hundred files.

The piece of code I use to perform the interpolation:

```
import numpy as np

zi=np.load(Array.npy)

x, y = np.indices(zi.shape)                                   
    
zi_i=griddata((x[~np.isnan(zi)], y[~np.isnan(zi)]), zi[~np.isnan(zi)(x[np.isnan(zi)],y[np.isnan(zi)]))
```

The result:
[image]

I put in link the array on which I work: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KvEomI3H-gow2yoF6e2zpv5OwkriG7TQ/view?usp=sharing.

Thank you for your help. I hope I have provided enough information.

Comment: can you please attach the images in the question itself instead of having them as hyperlinks

Comment: I would like to but I don't have the 10 reputation to do it..

Comment: i've addded it for you. Also is it possible for you to paste that array which you again have in a hyperlink?

Comment: Thanks for the change. For the array I don't know if it's possible or how to do it, its size is 700Mb in .npy file..